# Django: Built-in login fails with existing User

Tags: django, authentication

I have a question regarding django built in authentication system.

I'm following this [DjangoDoc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/).

So I added the URLS in my `urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from .views.views_user import *

from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

And here is my `login.html`:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
</form>

{# Assumes you setup the password_reset view in your URLconf #}
<p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Lost password?</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

So it renders correctly the template with the login form.
And I have some existing Users, we can see them with Postman:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "AdminEP",
        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$180000$ETFUyfQsKN6j$7GAACOTgYheVjtHdeOpVCLd3qhIxttolISGLqqjE50s=",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "maxpon@live.com",
        "is_a": false,
        "is_o": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "Max",
        "password": "12345678",
        "first_name": "Max",
        "last_name": "Pon",
        "email": "maxpon@live.com",
        "is_a": true,
        "is_o": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "username": "Seb",
        "password": "12345678",
        "first_name": "Seb",
        "last_name": "Pon",
        "email": "sebpon@live.com",
        "is_a": true,
        "is_o": false
    }
]
```

But when I try to log in I keep getting the message:

```
Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.
```

This message is in my template if the login fails, but I don't understand why it fails.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I don't get it.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear whether your JSON was edited inconsistently; it looks like you have a valid hash for the admin password, but the others look raw. If you have plaintext passwords in the DB, that won't work, as Django will attempt to compare hashes; to set a user's password, create them without one, then use [`user.set_password('raw password here')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) followed by `user.save()`.

Comment: Thanks @kungphu ! Using it in the shell works perfectly. But now I'm having another issue by intergrating this line in my User model, I've posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940700/django-unique-constraint-failed-user-username), if you could help me out once more it would be awesome.